# Does IBM Watson support using multiple language models at the same time?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, multilingual, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am dealing with conversations containing both English and Spanish, and Spanish is the primary language here. The situation is that English is interweaving with Spanish in some parts of the conversation, and I would like to tell them apart.
I know that we will pass in a model name as a parameter, but I feel like Watson does not support me to indicate a second language as another parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watson Speech to Text models are language specific, so you would need to pass the audio through two models via two separate API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Spanish node above the English node, keep English as the default node the nodes can be distinguished with the $lang context parameter also IBM Watson follows the top to bottom approach.